# What are the benefits from more iGPU memory?

Tags: integrated-graphics

I am using the Intel HD Grahpics integrated in the CPU and the BIOS setup lets me choose the amount of iGPU memory. I can choose between 32M, 64M, 96M and 128M. The default is 64M. I would like advice on how much iGPU memory I should choose.

When it comes to graphics I will use the system to watch videos, edit graphics and images and occasionally edit videos. Will I get a potential benefit from 128MB of VRAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no one answer.

If this is a headless machine that you will only be using remotely, set it to the minimum.

If you are going to be playing games, using anything graphically intensive or complex, set it the maximum.

One word of warning, (mainly to people coming here from Google), 32Mb is a "safe" amount, some older motherboards let you set this as low as 1Mb. This is not usually enough and can cause problems.... I experienced this on a D865GBF and D915GAF and had to basically pull the CMOS battery and force a reset.

Comment: When it comes to graphics I will use the system to watch videos, edit graphics and images and occasionally edit videos.

Comment: If your video editing tool can use graphic acceleration, set it to maximum - likewise, if you see lag or other issues in video playback.